# Лицензия на Packet Tracer

Tags: лицензирование, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

Интересует, где можно найти лицензию Packet Tracer от Cisco Academy. Можно ли его использовать в целях обучения бесплатно? И есть ли аналоги этого ПО?

Comment: Поскольку никогда не видел этого Packer Tracer'а, то ответить не могу. Но google выдал такую ссылку - http://www.gns3.net/. Может быть подойдёт?

Comment: Единственное, не понятно, под какой этот продукт лицензией. За ссылку спасибо, можно было как ответ добавить.

Comment: Может ответ и не в тему, но в университете некоторое время занимался на Packet Tracer 5.1. Вы про него? Он же вроде абсолютно бесплатный. Там даже есть свои tutorials.

Comment: Проблема в том что он доступен бесплатно только ученикам и учителям академии. И это везде пишут. Естественно есть способы его достать и я уже работал с 5.3. Собственно поэтому мне и стало интересно, можно ли его мне использовать или лицензия запрещает. Судя по ответам запрещает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программа, приведенная по ссылке alexiz, является свободным программным обеспечением и распространяется под GNU/GPL лицензией (2 или 3 - не знаю). Соответственно ее можно использовать, как угодно (почти).

Comment: А Packet Tracer распространяется под проприетарной лицензией и доступна бесплатно только студентам и преподавателям Академии Cisco.